# Nodetool repair erroring on cassandra 3.9 cluster complaining of dead nodes

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra 3.9 cluster. I initiated a repair from one of the nodes in the cluster. The repair went nowhere. I see the logs on that initiated node filled with errors like this.

```
ERROR [GossipTasks:1] 2018-02-16 23:27:36,949 RepairSession.java:347 - [repair #cadf6f11-1342-11e8-8d73-6767c6890f70] session completed with the following error
java.io.IOException: Endpoint /**.**.**.52 died
        at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession.convict(RepairSession.java:346) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.FailureDetector.interpret(FailureDetector.java:306) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doStatusCheck(Gossiper.java:782) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.access$800(Gossiper.java:66) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper$GossipTask.run(Gossiper.java:181) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:118) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

One the other hand if I look at the logs for the nodes claimed to be dead, I see one of 3 symptoms.

1. Either the node claims to have successfully sent the requested
   merkle tree over.
2. The node does not have any trace of the repair session, and thus doesn't appear to have received any repair request.
3. The node shows exception like this.

   ERROR [ValidationExecutor:3] 2018-02-16 23:29:06,548 Validator.java:261 - Failed creating a merkle tree for [repair #cac2bf50-1342-11e8-8d73-6767c6890f70 on somekeyspace/sometable, [(-3531087107126953137,-3495591103116433105], (1424707151780052485,1425479237398192865], (-3533012126945497873,-3531087107126953137], (1425479237398192865,1429220273719165251], (-4991682772598302168,-4984938905452900436], (-7686750611814623539,-7685228552629222537], (7554301216433235881,7559623046999138658], (334796420453180909,342318143371667659], (-3538876023288368831,-3533012126945497873], (1409514567521922418,1424707151780052485], (5391546013321073004,5393284101537339558], (590921410556013711,593440512568877190]]], /**.**.**.43 (see log for details)

   ERROR [ValidationExecutor:3] 2018-02-16 23:29:06,549 CassandraDaemon.java:226 - Exception in thread Thread[ValidationExecutor:3,1,main]
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parent repair session with id = c8bf7540-1342-11e8-8d73-6767c6890f70 has failed.
           at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.getParentRepairSession(ActiveRepairService.java:377) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.getSSTablesToValidate(CompactionManager.java:1313) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.doValidationCompaction(CompactionManager.java:1222) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.access$700(CompactionManager.java:81) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
           at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$11.call(CompactionManager.java:844) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Any pointers on this? I looked at a number of cassandra issues on JIRA. They all speak of hung repair. I am not sure how to tell if this is one of those cases. If I grep for any separate process by the name 'repair', I dont find any. Should I reattempt the repair? Should I restart nodes? This is my prod cluster and I have a lot of data in it. So I am vary of randomly experimenting. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.